# Retrieve Contacts from Viber PC

Tags: windows-8, contacts, viber

I am trying to retrieve contacts from Viber PC. I read the below mentioned solution on the website. However while running the command I am getting an error that Error: no such table: ContactRelation

Request you to kindly let me know how to resolve the said error.

download command-line shell for accessing and modifying SQLite databases and copy sqlite3.exe , viber.db and data.db to C:. Then in CMD(start -> run -> cmd.exe) position yourself on C:\ and enter sqlite3.exe viber.db
Then enter:

SELECT ContactRelation.Number, Contact.FirstName, Contact.SecondName FROM Contact INNER JOIN ContactRelation ON Contact.ContactID = ContactRelation.ContactID ORDER BY Contact.FirstName;

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you already found a solution to this or not, but for any future problems with this one , enter this line of code instead (since there is no table called ContactRelation in the viber database anymore , as far as i know) , all the contact data is actually only in the "Contact" table:

```
 SELECT  Contact.Name,Contact.Number FROM Contact ORDER BY Contact.Name;
```